# I want to determine the names of all the months between two dates using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime
import calendar

dateStart = datetime.date(2017, 8, 2)
dateEnd = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
st = dateStart.month
ed = dateEnd.month
lis = []

for i in range(st, ed + 1):
    lis.append(calendar.month_name[i])

print(lis)
```

The output that I am expecting is:

```
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

With `'January'` belonging to the year 2018. The list has to be sorted in accordance with the order of the months. This code isn't working for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `relativedelta`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime
import calendar

dateStart = datetime.date(2017,8,2)
dateEnd = datetime.date(2018,1,1)
st = datetime.date(dateStart.year, dateStart.month, 1)
ed = dateEnd

tmp = st
months = {}

while tmp <= dateEnd:
    months[tmp.month] = calendar.month_name[tmp.month]
    tmp += relativedelta(months=1)

lis = [months[k] for k in sorted(list(months.keys()))]
print(lis)
```

> ['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

Comment: Order of months has to be maintained. January must appear first even if it belongs to the next year

Comment: @MirMuhammadMurtaza there you go mister

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using only Python built-ins. Note that it's possible for a month to be repeated depending on the start and end dates.

```
import datetime
import calendar

dateStart = datetime.date(2017, 8, 2)
dateEnd = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)

ONE_DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
dt, ed = dateStart, dateEnd
lis = []
last_month = None

while dt <= ed:
    if dt.month != last_month:
        lis.append(dt.month)
        last_month = dt.month
    dt += ONE_DAY

# Sort the month numbers and replace them with their names.
lis = [calendar.month_name[month] for month in sorted(lis)]

print(lis)
```

Output:

```
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: @shahkalpesh: The OP's question also says "The list has to be sorted in accordance with the order of the months" which seems to contradict the expected output which shows `January` first. I interpreted it to mean the order the month occurred between the two dates. I don't think just sorting them alphabetically by their names is correct either, btw.

Comment: I agree with you. I edited the post based on the expected output. My apologies for doing it.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Think I figured out what they meant now.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `range()` when you enter `range(8,1)` it will return 0 step because you cannot increase 8 to 1.

you can try below code for little improvment:

```
if st < ed:
    for i in range(st, ed+1):
        lis.append(calendar.month_name[i])
else:
    for i in range(st, ed+1, -1):
        lis.append(calendar.month_name[i])
print(lis)
```

but don't forget if you use same mount this will not work. (2017, 8, 2 / 2018, 8, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator to iterate over the months. Preserves start and end dates.

```
import datetime
import calendar

dateStart = datetime.date(2017, 8, 2)
dateEnd = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)

def months(start, end):
    ''' Input a start and end date and yields a numerical month
        (between 1 and 12) for each month between the dates.
    '''
    # Include start month:
    if start < end:
        yield start.month
    while start < end: 
        if start.month < 12:  
            start = start.replace(month=start.month+1) 
        else:     
            start = start.replace(year=start.year+1).replace(month=1) 
        yield start.month 

months = [calendar.month_name[month] for month in
            sorted(set(months(dateStart, dateEnd)))] 

print(dateStart) 
print(dateEnd)
print(months)
```

Output:

```
2017-08-02
2018-01-01
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

The above will at most print 12 month names, even if the two dates are more than 12 months apart. If the requirement is to list repeated months in order it's a bit simpler (notice that I added a few months to `dateEnd` to illustrate).

```
import datetime
import calendar

dateStart = datetime.date(2017, 8, 2)
dateEnd = datetime.date(2018, 10, 1)

def months(start, end):
    ''' Input a start and end date and yields a numerical month
        (between 1 and 12) for each month between the dates.
    '''
    if start < end:
        yield calendar.month_name[start.month]
    while start < end:
        if start.month < 12: 
            start = start.replace(month=start.month+1)
        else:
            start = start.replace(year=start.year+1).replace(month=1)
        yield calendar.month_name[start.month]

months = [month for month in months(dateStart, dateEnd)]

print(months)
```

Output:

```
['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October']
```

Comment: if the dates are equal this returns `[]`.  If it should return the current month then change the first equality test to `<=`. If it should return the start month even if the end month is prior to start then remove the test, leave the `yield` (indent it though).